# Not able to generate logs from maven project

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I have created a maven project which contains test cases and its corresponding functionality. All the functionality for validation checks has been placed under src/main/java. Also test cases are part of src/test/java. I have placed below log4j.properties in src/main/resources.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=info, file,stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/tmp/reports/logs/log.out
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

#To console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Also in each of the class files I have added below line along with below imports:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

Initialization of logs:

```
static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(<class name>.class);
```

and am using `log.info("")` to create logs.

Also, in pom.xml, below dependencies are added:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
```

But I see logs are not generating both in console as well as in file `/tmp/reports/logs/log.out` but the log file `/tmp/reports/logs/log.out` is created successfully but no logs are appended also no logs produced in console.

I do see logs on console but they are definitely not in `log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n`
 format.

I am assuming that they are produced on console because I have imported log4j related jars.

Can some one please help on this ?

Comment: If it's for test cases only, wouldn't it be easier to just use slf4j-simple?

Comment: I used slf4j-simple jar as well, but still logs are not generated

Comment: slf4j-simple isn't for generating logs, it's for outputting your log statements to the standard output, so you can see what's going on during the unit test, nothing more.

Comment: Okay, but in this case, it is more than unit test cases. The logs needs to be saved to understand what did not go well. Also I generate reports end of every run which needs to say "Look at logs for more info" on an error/exception. So, I needed to log them somewhere. Everything works fine except generation of logs (which is actually important)

Comment: I'm not exactly an expert on Log4J 1.x config, so I can't help you there. It's just that in most cases I've seen the test logs are simply written to stdout and retained by the build server (for instance, Jenkins), so finding out what went wrong is simply a matter of scrolling through Jenkins output. That said: if this is not adequate for your use case then disregard my comments.

Comment: Absolutely yes, we can check in jenkins logs, but unfortunately the test env is not configured yet.. so till then storing on a log file is needed..

Answer (score 0):

I used Log4j logger instead of slf4j and logs were generated. Its a work around used.

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(KNMIRules.class);
```